# Image preview not displayed correctly using drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to get my images to display correctly just below the drag-n-drop area which I've defined in my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gKVKm/2030/) in my Chrome browser.
Before I try to upload my image using either of the technique(drag-n-drop or button), there appears to be an area for where the image will be shown.

Is there a way so that my images will be displayed just below the drag-n-drop area and not be sticking below to the "or click here" button?

Can we get rid of the background lines which appear where the image will be received?
Also there seems to be no way one will know if the image has been uploaded or not. Can something be done about these issues?

HTML:

```
<div id="drop-zone">
                Drop files here...
    <div id="clickHere">
        or click here..
    </div>
        <img id="blb" width = "400px" height = "250px" />
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="document.getElementById('blb').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#drop-zone {
    /*Sort of important*/
    width: 300px;
    /*Sort of important*/
    height: 200px;
    position: left;
    left:50%;
    top:100px;
    margin-left:-150px;
    border: 2px dashed rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 180px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

    #drop-zone input {
        /*Important*/
        position: absolute;
        /*Important*/
        cursor: pointer;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        /* Important This is only comment out for demonstration purposes. */
        opacity:0;
    }

    /*Important*/
    #drop-zone.mouse-over {
        border: 2px dashed rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    }


/*If you dont want the button*/
#clickHere {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    line-height: 26px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 26px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #3b85c3;

}

    #clickHere:hover {
        background-color: #4499DD;

    }
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var dropZoneId = "drop-zone";
    var buttonId = "clickHere";
    var mouseOverClass = "mouse-over";

    var dropZone = $("#" + dropZoneId);
    var ooleft = dropZone.offset().left;
    var ooright = dropZone.outerWidth() + ooleft;
    var ootop = dropZone.offset().top;
    var oobottom = dropZone.outerHeight() + ootop;
    var inputFile = dropZone.find("input");
    document.getElementById(dropZoneId).addEventListener("dragover", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        dropZone.addClass(mouseOverClass);
        var x = e.pageX;
        var y = e.pageY;

        if (!(x < ooleft || x > ooright || y < ootop || y > oobottom)) {
            inputFile.offset({ top: y - 15, left: x - 100 });
        } else {
            inputFile.offset({ top: -400, left: -400 });
        }

    }, true);

    if (buttonId != "") {
        var clickZone = $("#" + buttonId);

        var oleft = clickZone.offset().left;
        var oright = clickZone.outerWidth() + oleft;
        var otop = clickZone.offset().top;
        var obottom = clickZone.outerHeight() + otop;

        $("#" + buttonId).mousemove(function (e) {
            var x = e.pageX;
            var y = e.pageY;
            if (!(x < oleft || x > oright || y < otop || y > obottom)) {
                inputFile.offset({ top: y - 15, left: x - 160 });
            } else {
                inputFile.offset({ top: -400, left: -400 });
            }
        });
    }

    document.getElementById(dropZoneId).addEventListener("drop", function (e) {
        $("#" + dropZoneId).removeClass(mouseOverClass);
    }, true);

})
```

Comment: first close the button div  <div id="clickHere">or click here..</div>

Comment: yeah @godfather. A mistake. Corrected